# Attack mechanism

Tags: internal-consistency, xenobiology, biochemistry, bio-mechanics

My creature attack was basically generated by releasing a stream of super-cooled and super-heated air at the same time which, when they interact with the addition of a strong gust of wind, generates a vicious horizontal cyclone that rips through the air and slams into an opponent at full force."It evolved on incredible pressure which earth animals never visited.It scales which are coated like hair filaments which allows it to lower damage received by half
.what materials is it reinforced ?how this attack is generated this attack name aero burster ?and possible chemical reaction?, chemical reactants mixed to generate this attack ? Can this  of this work in realistic way?
(The first attack i mentioned in this description)

Comment: We deal with one clear focused question per post. You're welcome to ask several linked questions in their own threads - we like that.

Comment: Things that evolved to live in extreme environments usually adapted only to survive in said environments from an external perspective. Some Whale species and several underwater creatures spend prolonged periods (sometimes their entire lives) under pressures that would instantly crush a normal creature living on the surface. That doesn't mean that they needed to become able to shoot pressurized water jets that can cut steel, just that they needed to be really good at not being crushed themselves. Kinda like how desert creatures are good at preventing dehydration, but not at breathing fire.

Comment: Look at pistol and mantis shrimps for example: they live in more than survivable environments for your average animal, yet they can exploit the water they live in to create cavitation bubbles, boiling the water around and creating tiny Shockwaves through sheer pressure (but no, scaling it doesn't work for earth biology, nor does it work out when they aren't submerged in water).

Answer (score 8):

## No, it is not realistic (so make it magical/fantasy)

Hello, and welcome to Worldbuilding!

There are several problems with this concept...

1. Generating cold. This is – as far as we know — very difficult to do. Endothermic chemical reactions exist, but they are exceedingly rare, and the results never lead to anything being "super-cooled".
2. There is nothing about very cool and very warm air mixing that leads to anything spectacular, not in the size range of animals. You are thinking about *cyclones*, which are nation-sized *weather systems*, not local phenomena. This kind of thing — by the way — happens all the time, and it never
   leads to anything spectacular. For example:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Neq8AOgcOVk
3. If you want to use chemistry to make a violent puff of air, no cold or heat is necessary. Any chemical reaction that generates lots of gas in an enclosed cavity, and that is then funneled towards a target, will do.

So I must say that your concept belongs firmly in the realm of fantasy rather than anything physics-based. In fantasy, this would be just fine, and you would instead do well to *not try to explain this* based on any kind of real-world physics, because then you just ruin the magic.